# WinRT localisation with split resource files

Tags: localization, windows-runtime

I'd like to have separate my translations across multiple files.

To keep Controls separate from Dialog text for example.

How can we split language resource files (.resw) across multiple files? and how can they be referenced in XAML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reference separate files by using the format:

**Strings/en-US/Errors.resw**

**XAML**

```
<TextBlock x:Uid="/Errors/AlreadyRegistered"></TextBlock>
```

**Code**

```
var res =  Windows.ApplicationModel.ResourceLoader('Errors');
res.GetString('AlreadyRegistered');
```

More information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965323.aspx).

**Note:** The localised values are **only swapped out at runtime** so you'll need to specify the `Text` / `Content` `XAML` properties if you want to see any content in the designer.

**Automation Properties** need to be set like this:

```
MyControlName.[using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Automation]AutomationProperties.Name
```